# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Connector: HTTP Error: Bad Request

Tags: typescript, graphql

i am using stepzen and graphql for fetching an api but when trying it with link it is working but when using graphql it is showing bad request i think it has something to do with query that i am passing but i tried and couldnt catch it and it is not showing which line is producing error

**facing issue **

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Connector: HTTP Error: Bad Request

Call Stack
call
node_modules\@apollo\client\errors\errors.cjs (31:27)
eval
node_modules\@apollo\client\core\core.cjs (1843:46)
examiner
node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs (1072:52)
callback
node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs (1065:71)
new Promise
<anonymous>
Object.then
node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs (1065:23)
then
node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs (1073:48)
call
node_modules\zen-observable\lib\Observable.js (135:17)
notifySubscription
node_modules\zen-observable\lib\Observable.js (179:2)
onNotify
node_modules\zen-observable\lib\Observable.js (235:6)
argument
node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs (1055:68)
Array.forEach
<anonymous>
forEach
node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs (1055:24)
iterateObserversSafely
node_modules\@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs (1147:20)
call
node_modules\zen-observable\lib\Observable.js (135:17)
notifySubscription
node_modules\zen-observable\lib\Observable.js (179:2)
onNotify
node_modules\zen-observable\lib\Observable.js (235:6)
call
node_modules\@apollo\client\link\http\http.cjs (329:69)
```

**my query **

```
import {gql} from '@apollo/client'

export const fetchWeatherQueries = gql`
  query MyQuery (
    $current_weather: String
      $daily: String = " weathercode,temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,apparent_temperature_max,apparent_temperature_min,sunrise,sunset,uv_index_max,uv_index_clear_sky_max"
      $hourly: String = "temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,apparent_temperature,precipitation_probability,precipitation,rain,showers,snowfall,snow_depth,visibility,windgusts_10m,uv_index,uv_index_clear_sky"
      $latitude: String!
      $longitude: String!
      $timezone: String!
  )  {
    myQuery(
      current_weather: $current_weather
      daily: $daily
      hourly: $hourly
      latitude: $latitude
      longitude: $longitude
      timezone: $timezone
    ) {
      elevation
      generationtime_ms
      latitude
      longitude
      timezone
      timezone_abbreviation
      utc_offset_seconds
      daily_units {
        apparent_temperature_max
        apparent_temperature_min
        sunrise
        sunset
        temperature_2m_max
        time
        temperature_2m_min
        uv_index_clear_sky_max
        uv_index_max
        weathercode
      }
      hourly {
        apparent_temperature
        precipitation
        precipitation_probability
        rain
        relativehumidity_2m
        showers
        snow_depth
        snowfall
        temperature_2m
        time
        uv_index
        uv_index_clear_sky
        visibility
        windgusts_10m
      }
      hourly_units {
        windgusts_10m
        visibility
        uv_index_clear_sky
        uv_index
        time
        temperature_2m
        snowfall
        snow_depth
        showers
        relativehumidity_2m
        rain
        precipitation_probability
        precipitation
        apparent_temperature
      }
      current_weather {
        is_day
        temperature
        time
        weathercode
        winddirection
        windspeed
      }
      daily {
        apparent_temperature_max
        apparent_temperature_min
        sunrise
        sunset
        temperature_2m_max
        temperature_2m_min
        time
        uv_index_clear_sky_max
        uv_index_max
        weathercode
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

**my component page **

```
import { getClient } from "@/apollo-client"
import {fetchWeatherQueries} from "@/graphql/queries/fetchWeatherQueries"

type Props ={
  params:{
    city:string,
    latitude:string,
    longitude:string
  }
}

async function WeatherPage({params : {city , latitude , longitude}}:Props) {
  const client = getClient();

  const {data} = await client.query({
    query: fetchWeatherQueries,
    variables:{
      current_weather: "true",
      latitude : latitude,
      longitude : longitude,
      timezone : "auto",
    }
  })

  const results : Root = data.myQuery;

}
```

i am giving the link of api if it helps

"https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=51.51&longitude=0.13&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,apparent_temperature,precipitation_probability,precipitation,rain,showers,snowfall,snow_depth,visibility,windgusts_10m,uv_index,uv_index_clear_sky&daily=weathercode,temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,apparent_temperature_max,apparent_temperature_min,sunrise,sunset,uv_index_max,uv_index_clear_sky_max&current_weather=true&timezone=auto"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside my query one space was extra
correct one is here :

```js
export const fetchWeatherQueries = gql`
  query MyQuery (
    $current_weather: String
      $daily: String = "weathercode,temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,apparent_temperature_max,apparent_temperature_min,sunrise,sunset,uv_index_max,uv_index_clear_sky_max"
      $hourly: String = "temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,apparent_temperature,precipitation_probability,precipitation,rain,showers,snowfall,snow_depth,visibility,windgusts_10m,uv_index,uv_index_clear_sky"
      $latitude: String!
      $longitude: String!
      $timezone: String!
  )  {
```